# Result in console is empty jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get total-page text from aliexpress, i tried to get it with jquery but in console it returns empty result, can someone help me please? i want to get text of this variable here is my code,

```
let lastPage = parseInt($('.total-page').text())
console.log(lastPage);
```

Comment: first problem you are missing a `)` at the end of  `parseInt($('.total-page').text()` second please include the relevant html.

Comment: how include the relevant html, can u show me example please?

Comment: Just like you did with the jquery code, Cope your html code and paste it when you edit the question